# Can not complete paypal payment in flutter app

Tags: flutter, webview, paypal

I'm trying to integrate paypal in my flutter app like in this page [https://medium.com/flutter-community/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-flutter-379fbb3b87f5](https://stackoverflow.com) . My flutter version is 3.0.5. In this page Restapi v1 is used, but now v2 is used. **I have successfully executed payments with Postman**. But in flutter I face unusual problem in method for creating order.

This is modified createPaypalPayment  method:

```
 Future<Map<String, String>> createPaypalPayment(
      transactions, accessToken) async {
    try {
      var uri = Uri.parse('$domain/v2/checkout/orders');
      var jsonRequest = jsonEncode(transactions);
      var response = await http.post(
        uri,
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken'
        },
        body: jsonRequest,
      );

       print(response.body.toString());
      

      final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        if (body["links"] != null && body["links"].length > 0) {
          List links = body["links"];

          String executeUrl = "";
          String approvalUrl = "";
          final item = links.firstWhere((o) => o["rel"] == "approval_url",
              orElse: () => null);
          if (item != null) {
            approvalUrl = item["href"];
          }
          final item1 = links.firstWhere((o) => o["rel"] == "execute",
              orElse: () => null);
          if (item1 != null) {
            executeUrl = item1["href"];
          }
          return {"executeUrl": executeUrl, "approvalUrl": approvalUrl};
        }
        return {};
      } else {
        print("HTTP Error: ${response.statusCode}");
        print("Error Body: ${response.body}");
        return {};
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Exception: $e");
    throw Exception(e.toString());
      
    }
  }
```

I debugged app, and I have founded out that function is finished at line where is post method called. It doesn't go any further. It doesn't throw exception or error. Response body is printed in debug console terminal with id of order and links, which means that order is created, but it doesn' go any further and returns empty object.

Those are dependencies that I use in this flutter app:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.5
  http_auth: ^1.0.0
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.4
```

Also there is bunch of blue text in debug console. When I press "Pay with PayPal" button this is always written in debug console: *E/FrameEvents(11906): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame*.

I also wonder will I have to do modifications with executePayment method, but because I'm stuck with createPaypalPayment method I can't try anything with it?